# Refer to model field by string variable that contains the name of the field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out how to word this for a google search - pardon.   If I have a model like:

```
c = Color.all
```

I could say:

```
c.Color[0].color_name
```

So if I then have  a variable that contains the name of a field in that model like:

```
b = 'color_name'
```

How could I say ("c.color_name") like this using the string with the field name:

```
c[0].b
```

Or, I mean tell Ruby/Rails to use the contents of the vaiable as the field name:

```
c[0].[the string value of b]
```

I've fumbled around trying everything I can think of but the syntax for this I can't figure out.

Thanks!

Rails 2.3.5 / Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `b` is an instance variable or method of a `Color`, use the [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-send) method from `Object`

```
c = Color.all
b = 'color_name'
c[0].send(b.to_sym)
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used this version of rails, but `object['nameoffield']` or `object.read_attribute('nameoffield')` might work.